# How do I create a zoom in/zoom out feature like in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, zooming

I want to create a web based tool that allows people to visualise semantic web ontologies. The visualisation will look like a tree structure. I want people to be able to zoom in and zoom out the way they can with Google Maps, to get a close look to make a selection or to get a overview of the main topics etc.

Can you provide some pointers regarding the zoom in/zoom out part. Maybe a jQuery library that provides these features?

PS: I know such tools already exist, but I think I have a few new ideas to try out during my weekends.